# value.map is not a function in Sequelize findAll with or Param

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Can somebody help me to fix this my error, there's my code:

```
const { UserLogs } = require("../models");

let logscontroller = {};

logscontroller.getAll = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let search = req.body.search.value;
  console.log(search);
  if (search === "") {
    UserLogs.findAll({
      offset: req.body.start,
      limit: req.body.length,
      order: [["id", "ASC"]],
      raw: true
    })
      .then(result => {
        res.json({
          data: result
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  } else {
    UserLogs.findAll({
      where: {
        email: {
          $or: search
        }
      },
      offset: req.body.start,
      limit: req.body.length,
      order: [["id", "ASC"]],
      raw: true
    })
      .then(result => {
        res.json({
          data: result
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  return;
};

logscontroller.index = (req, res) => {
  res.render("logs", {
    title: "Logs Users"
  });
};

module.exports = logscontroller;
```

And There's My Error, I Don't know why..

> TypeError: value.map is not a function
>       at Object._whereBind (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2180:21)
>       at Object.whereItemQuery (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2070:19)
>       at Utils.getComplexKeys.forEach.prop (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1957:25)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object.whereItemsQuery (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1955:35)
>       at Object.getWhereConditions (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2423:19)
>       at Object.selectQuery (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1133:28)
>       at QueryInterface.select (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\query-interface.js:1077:27)
>       at Promise.try.then.then.then (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1596:34)
>       at tryCatcher (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (D:\HASH\back-office-2\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)

Answer (score 0):

as per the **[Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)** , `$or` accepts array:

```
$or : [{authorId: 12}, {authorId: 13}]
```

and this is what you have used

```
email: {
    $or: search
}
```

---

I think what you need is :

```
email : search // for exact match

or 

email : {
    $ilke : `%${search}%` // for partial match
}
```